# VBA Macro, Sort column alphabetically with rows following, how?

Tags: excel, vba

Multiple columns and rows. I want to sort one column alphabetically so that also the corresponding data in the rows will be sorted with it and not just the column. I am having trouble finding the right VBA code for that, could anyone please help with the code to do that task? thanks.

Comment: Give [Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) a try, it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA?  Data and Filter will get you what you want or a Sort.  Of course those can be emulated in VBA but it only makes sense to do so if you are processing a lot of data that might update several times.  If you are doing this task one time, just use the excel tools.